Create columns with the number of days depending on the number of existing columns
I have a dataframe with products and discounts like this
product disc1 disc2 dateini1     dateini2   total
p1      10    2     2024-04-05  2024-04-20 2
p2      5     4     2020-01-20  2024-04-15 2
p3      10    NA    2022-10-20  NA         1
p4      10    NA    2024-04-10  NA         1

I need to find the number of days that each discount was available in the reference month, in this case April. But I have different cases and so I need the result of my table.
product disc1 disc2 dateini1     dateini2    ndays1 ndays2
p1      10    2     2024-04-05  2024-04-20  15     11        
p2      5     4     2020-01-20  2024-04-15  15     15
p3      10    NA    2022-10-20  NA          30
p4      10    NA    2024-04-10  NA          21

I have already achieved it for cases where I only have one discount available with the following code, but I need to generalize it for when I have several discounts, and in other months I could have 3 or more discounts for a specific product.
per_actual <- as.Date("2024-04-01")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$total[i] == 1 & df$dateini1[i] <= per_actual) {
    df$ndays1[i] <- days_in_month(per_actual)
  } else {
    df$ndays1[i] <- as.Date(days_in_month(per_actual) + per_actual) - df$dateini1[i]
  }
}

I need some idea to automate it, even changing the code I have at the moment

Hey @dvera, could you please explain better your expected output? How ndays should be calculated? From datini to the last day of it's month? On your code, it appears that datini is mispelled dateini.

Hello, I have already updated the error.  When there is a single discount there are only two options, the date of the discount starts outside the reference period (April) in this case ndays must be the total number of days in the month, in my result it is the case of p3.  The other option is that the start date (dateini1) begins within the reference period. In this case, the days must be counted from that date to the end of the month.  I think I solve this with my code.

My problem is when I have more than two discounts available.  If the first date is outside the reference period, you must count the days from April 1st to the next date (dateini2) and then the days from dateini2 to the end of the month (April 30).  But if the initial date 1 (dateini1) starts in the reference period,  I need to count the days from that date to date 2 (dateini2) and then count from dateini2 to the end of the month (April 30), and I could have even more than 2 discounts at the same time.  I hope I have made myself understood, thank you very much in advance.

Here is a data.table approach, with some lubridate for date/periodd wrangling.
The functionality:

create an interval to measure to (here: April 1st until April 30th)
melt data to long format, so each discount gets it's own row
create an interval for each discount
calculate the duration of the overlap of ceach dictoun-interval with the measure-periode-interval (in days)
cast to wide format again

sample data
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# sample data
mydata <- fread("product disc1 disc2 dateini1     dateini2   total
p1      10    2     2024-04-05  2024-04-20 2
p2      5     4     2020-01-20  2024-04-15 2
p3      10    NA    2022-10-20  NA         1
p4      10    NA    2024-04-10  NA         1")
# or setDT(mydata)

per_actual <- as.IDate("2024-04-01")

code
#melt to long format, remove incomplete rows
DT <- melt(mydata, id.vars = "product", 
     measure.vars = patterns(disc = "^disc", dateini = "^dateini"), 
     na.rm = TRUE)
# just to make sure, sort/key by product and dateini
setkey(DT, product, dateini)
# create end of discount period
DT[, end := shift(dateini, type = "lead") - 1, by = product]
# fill in NA
DT[is.na(end), end := ceiling_date(per_actual, unit = "months") - 1]
DT[, disc_interval := interval(start = dateini, end = end)]
# Key: <product, dateini>
#    product variable  disc    dateini        end                  disc_interval
#     <char>   <fctr> <int>     <IDat>     <IDat>                     <Interval>
# 1:      p1        1    10 2024-04-05 2024-04-20 2024-04-05 UTC--2024-04-20 UTC
# 2:      p1        2     2 2024-04-20 2024-04-30 2024-04-20 UTC--2024-04-30 UTC
# 3:      p2        1     5 2020-01-20 2024-04-15 2020-01-20 UTC--2024-04-15 UTC
# 4:      p2        2     4 2024-04-15 2024-04-30 2024-04-15 UTC--2024-04-30 UTC
# 5:      p3        1    10 2022-10-20 2024-04-30 2022-10-20 UTC--2024-04-30 UTC
# 6:      p4        1    10 2024-04-10 2024-04-30 2024-04-10 UTC--2024-04-30 UTC

# get the interval to look at (per_actula until end of month)
per_interval <- lubridate::interval(start = per_actual, 
                                    end = ceiling_date(per_actual, unit = "months") - 1)
# calculate the overlap in days (you can supress warnings if desired)
DT[, ndays := as.duration(lubridate::intersect(disc_interval, per_interval)) |> day()]
# cast to wide again
dcast(DT, product ~ variable, value.var = c("disc", "dateini", "ndays"))

final output
# Key: <product>
#    product disc_1 disc_2  dateini_1  dateini_2 ndays_1 ndays_2
#     <char>  <int>  <int>     <IDat>     <IDat>   <int>   <int>
# 1:      p1     10      2 2024-04-05 2024-04-20      15      11
# 2:      p2      5      4 2020-01-20 2024-04-15      14      16
# 3:      p3     10     NA 2022-10-20       <NA>      30      NA
# 4:      p4     10     NA 2024-04-10       <NA>      21      NA


Thanks for the better explanation.
I think my alternative is somewhat similar to @Wimpel's one, but without data.table.
Check it out:
(Toy data disc_df at the end)
library(tidyverse) # `dplyr` and `lubridate`

# ----------------
# Whatever ref date will be brought to the first day of the month
ref_date <- ymd("2022-02-10")
ref_date <- floor_date(ref_date, unit = "months")

# Step 1: a longer format  allows managing multiple discounts
new_disc_df <- disc_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("_\\d+$"),          
    names_to = c(".value", "disc_id"), 
    names_pattern = "(.+)_([^_]+$)",  
    values_drop_na = TRUE)

# Step 2: Calculate `n_days`
new_disc_df <- new_disc_df%>% 
  mutate(
    .by = product,
    
    n_days = lead(ini_date, default = ceiling_date(ref_date, "months") - days(1)),
    n_days = as.integer(n_days - ini_date)) 

# Step 3: Brings it back to a wider format
new_disc_df <- new_disc_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(product, total),
    names_from = disc_id,
    names_glue = "{.value}_{disc_id}",
    names_vary = "slowest", # Keep disc, ini_date and n_days together
    values_from = c(disc, ini_date, n_days))

The output:
> new_disc_df              
# A tibble: 5 × 11
  product total disc_1 ini_date_1 n_days_1 disc_2 ini_date_2 n_days_2 disc_3 ini_date_3 n_days_3
  <chr>   <int>  <dbl> <date>        <int>  <dbl> <date>        <int>  <dbl> <date>        <int>
1 p01        36     15 2022-01-19       12     35 2022-01-31       17     40 2022-02-17       11
2 p02        33     10 2022-01-08       29     15 2022-02-06       16     25 2022-02-22        6
3 p03        28     20 2022-02-14        4     45 2022-02-18       10     NA NA               NA
4 p04        43     40 2022-02-12        5     40 2022-02-17       11     NA NA               NA
5 p05        21     25 2022-02-10       18     NA NA               NA     NA NA               NA


Toy data:
disc_df <- structure(list(
  product    = c("p01", "p02", "p03", "p04", "p05"), 
  disc_1     = c(15, 10, 20, 40, 25), 
  disc_2     = c(35, 15, 45, 40, NA), 
  disc_3     = c(40, 25, NA, NA, NA), 
  ini_date_1 = structure(c(19011, 19000, 19037, 19035, 19033), class = "Date"), 
  ini_date_2 = structure(c(19030, 19029, 19041, 19040, NA), class = "Date"), 
  ini_date_3 = structure(c(19040, 19045, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
  total      = c(36L, 33L, 28L, 43L, 21L)), 
  
  class      = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names  = c(NA, -5L))


Thank you, it helped me a lot to adapt the solution to the tidyverse. Because I needed that if a start date was outside the ref_date month it would only count the number of days from the first day of the ref_date month until the next start date appeared. But I was already able to adapt it with the two solutions that you provided me, thank you very much.
